# Use IN operator in THEN Statement in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a SQL statement which will get the information from table valued parameter based on the input given in stored procedure. The condition should work if the input value row count greater than zero. Please guide me with the below query.

```
DECLARE @DivisionIds [dbo].[IDList]
DECLARE @StateIds [dbo].[IDList]

INSERT INTO @DivisionIds Values (1)
INSERT INTO @DivisionIds Values (1)
INSERT INTO @StateIds Values (1)
INSERT INTO @StateIds Values (3)
INSERT INTO @StateIds Values (31)
INSERT INTO @StateIds Values (43)

SET @DivsionRowCount = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM @DivisionIds)
SET @StateRowCount = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM @StateIds)

SELECT * FROM MedInv inv INNER JOIN Location loc ON inv.MedInvID = loc.MedInvID 
WHERE CustomerID = 210
AND
    @DivsionRowCount > 0 AND loc.DivisionID IN (SELECT ID FROM @DivisionIds)
AND
    @StateRowCount > 0 AND loc.StateID IN (SELECT ID FROM @StateIds)
```

The above code works fine, if I provide value for @DivisionIds and @StateIds. In some scenario @DivisionIds and StateIds does not have any values. So row count will be zero. I want to run the above condition only if the row count is greater than zero. How to do that?

My actual code contains the CASE statement for other conditions, I want to include the above condition in CASE statement, I tried the below approach but I am getting error.

```
DECLARE @DivisionIds [dbo].[IDList]
DECLARE @StateIds [dbo].[IDList]

SET @DivsionRowCount = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM @DivisionIds)
SET @StateRowCount = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM @StateIds)

SELECT CustomerName, InvEstValue, Status FROM MedInv inv
INNER JOIN Location loc ON loc.MedInvID = inv.MedInvID
INNER JOIN Division div ON div.DivisionID = loc.DivisionID
INNER JOIN State st ON st.StateID = loc.StateID
WHERE inv.CustomerID = 210
AND
inv.CustomerName Like
CASE WHEN @CustomerName = '' THEN '%%' ELSE '%' + @CustomerName + '%' END
AND
   inv.AssetDescription Like
   CASE WHEN @AssetDescription = '' THEN '%%' ELSE '%' + @AssetDescription + '%' END
AND
    @DivsionRowCount > 0 AND loc.DivisionID IN (SELECT ID FROM @DivisionIds)
AND
    @StateRowCount > 0 AND loc.StateID IN (SELECT ID FROM @StateIds)
AND
    loc.DivisionID = 
    CASE WHEN (@DivsionRowCount > 0) THEN loc.DivisionID IN (SELECT ID FROM @DivisionIds) ELSE loc.DivisionID END
```

from the above, I am getting error near to `IN` and `ELSE` keywords saying that Incorrect Syntax near `IN`, Incorrect syntax near `ELSE` . Expecting `END` OR `THEN`.

Please guide me how to use `IN` operator in `THEN` statement.

I am expecting the condition should run only if the input value parameter count is greater than zero.

Comment: You are getting the error because you are trying to fetch **loc.DivisionID** like a subquery which is incorrect.

Comment: You can't use case as a flow control. It's an expression that's returning a single value.

Comment: How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you take the right approach with you case when in your condition but 
The problem is that you with your last condition you'll have something like :

```
loc.DivisionID = in(...)
```

And "= in" is incorrect syntax

Maybe you can add your condition directly in the join

```
INNER JOIN Division div ON loc.DivisionID IN (SELECT ID FROM @DivisionIds)
```

Is that what you expected ?
But I think that you need also to put these 2 conditions in the join

```
AND
    @DivsionRowCount > 0 AND loc.DivisionID IN (SELECT ID FROM @DivisionIds)
AND
    @StateRowCount > 0 AND loc.StateID IN (SELECT ID FROM @StateIds)
```

Comment: Thanks Carbon provided the solution. The INNER JOIN works for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write it:

```
DECLARE @DivisionIds [dbo].[IDList]
DECLARE @StateIds [dbo].[IDList]

SET @DivsionRowCount = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM @DivisionIds)
SET @StateRowCount = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM @StateIds)

SELECT CustomerName, InvEstValue, Status 
FROM MedInv inv
INNER JOIN Location loc 
    ON loc.MedInvID = inv.MedInvID
INNER JOIN Division div 
    ON div.DivisionID = loc.DivisionID
INNER JOIN State st 
    ON st.StateID = loc.StateID
WHERE inv.CustomerID = 210
AND (@CustomerName = '' OR inv.CustomerName Like '%' + @CustomerName + '%')
AND (@AssetDescription = '' OR inv.AssetDescription LIKE '%' + @AssetDescription + '%')

AND (@DivsionRowCount = 0 OR loc.DivisionID IN (SELECT ID FROM @DivisionIds))
AND (@StateRowCount = 0 OR loc.StateID IN (SELECT ID FROM @StateIds))
```

You might want to add option(recompile) if you get performance problems. 
Check out [revisiting catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) on SQL in the wild blog for details.